# CSS Random background image position within range and increment; random number for transformation timing

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-animations

I am working off of a 480x480px sprite, with 225 individual 32x32px images laid out 15x15 grid so it's a perfectly square jpeg. I am trying to:

1. Create a way to generate random numbers in the background-position fields that will inject a random number within the range and increment I specify (range would be 0-480, inc is 32). This is in order to call random sprite background images for the div.
2. Generate a similar random number (just range) to be used in the timing of a div transform: rotateY(180deg) style. This is in order to get the div to "flip" and return. I have a front/back transition that already works in the code, but of course the timing is uniform.
3. Find a way to clone or duplicate that div, and its contents to fill a containing one.

I've been working to try and make something that would work like:

```
<div class="face back" style="
background-position-x: [myNumber]px;
background-position-y: [myNumber]px;
"></div>
```

Using a script such as:

```
var myNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*14)+1);
myNumber = myNumber *32;
```

I know I haven't been going about it the right way at all.

The desired result is a div (background or footer maybe) with dozens (maybe hundreds) of 32x32px seemingly random images. Each one transitioning at different intervals to different images. Obviously I'm looking for any elegant way.

Comment: To make me understand what you are trying to achieve here: Something like a photowall out of small images that are randomly choosen und behave randomly?

Comment: @toxicate20 Yes. The only way I know to make this work would be to style hundreds (or however many you'd need to fill the space. Keep in mind I might use this in a footer so it might need to be over 2000px wide) of individual css classes, each with individual timings. From there, mark them in the html individually with unique background positions. It's not practical

Comment: The main issue is I Can't find a way to use any random number in the stylesheet or html in a useful way. I need it to generate in the x and y background positions, and another separate random function for the timings. Apart from that, I need some way to copy repeat the div continuously with these dynamic measurements recalculating each time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure about what you are about but I would suggest the following procedure:

1. get an reference to the `<div>` that should be filled up with the tiled grid of images.
2. get its width and height and modulo divide (`%`) these values by the tile width plus one:

   var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

   var numTiles = ( rect.width % tileWidth + 1 ) * ( rect.height % tileWidth + 1 );
3. create `numTiles` is `<div>` elements and set their background position randomly:

   var bgTop = Math.floor( Math.random() * numTilesInMap );

   var bgLeft = Math.floor( Math.random() * numTilesInMap );
4. I would simply float all the div elements and append them to the container, thereby the container should have `overflow : hidden` because the grid is always a big bigger.

If you want to have unique random numbers and only as much tiles as images available in the map, than you can do something like this:

```
var randoms = {};
for( var i = 0; i < numImages.length; i++ ){
    randoms[i] = i;
};

var rand, index;
while( Object.keys( randoms ).length > 0 ){
    index = Math.round( Math.random() * ( Object.keys( randoms ).length - 1 ) );
    rand = randoms[ index ];

    //do something with the random number here

    delete randoms[ index ];
}
```

I have not tested this, it should just deal as suggestion how to generate random unique numbers. It can also be done with an array what perhaps is faster.

Greetings...

**Edit**

What I forgot to mention here is that next to the »div« solution you can also create a `<canvas>` and use the `drawImage()` method with random values, where you just draw regions of the tile map on the canvas as long as it is full. That reduces the size of the DOM and you can create the canvas it the exact size of the container. If you do not catch any events that lead to the area of the tilemap or another image depended reference this might be the fastest solution.

Comment: on the right track. ended up with: `var imageHeightWidth = 480;
var tileHeightWidth = 32;
    
function imageArray(imageSize, tileSize) {
    var imageTiles = (imageSize / tileSize);
    var imageTileArray = [0]
    for(i = 1; i < imageTiles; i++) {
        var tilePush = i * tileSize;
        imageTileArray.push(tilePush);
    }

    return(imageTileArray);
}
    
function randomTile(tileGen){
    var arrayLength = tileGen.length;
    return(tileGen[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayLength)]);
}

var imageTileArray = imageArray(imageHeightWidth, tileHeightWidth);`

Answer (score 0):

```
procces= function() {
  TimeSpeed=100;
  startRange=1;
  stopRange=100;
  incrementRenge=5;
  setTimeout(function run(){
        if(startRange >=stopRange) {
          console.info("stop");
        }
        else {
          console.info("rinning");
          startRange+=Math.floor(Math.random()*incrementRenge);
          $(".face back").css({"background-position":startRange+"px ,"+startRange+"px"});
          setTimeout(function() {
            run()
          },TimeSpeed) 
        }
      },TimeSpeed)
}
```